# how to change ringer mode (Silent or Vibrate)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

Is there any way (even a single way) to change ringer mode of iPhone (silent or vibrate) through our own app (don't worry about the app store). Kindly share with all if you know any as many developers want to explore this side.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. Private API is illegal to access. Recommended not to make these kind of apps.

Comment: Private API is not _illegal_ to access. You just won't be allowed in the App Store, and the OP said "Don't worry about the app store".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, Apple doesn't want devs messing with the basic phone functionality.